# Ebay OAuth fails - possibly due to international issues

Tags: oauth, ebay-api

I have built out the OAuth process to allow customers using our app to integrate with Ebay. The OAuth works like a charm for most customers, but there is one customer in particular (based out of the UK, we are based out of US) who is unable to authenticate. I have had the customer use a variety of browsers, and even use incognito mode. However he is still unable to authenticate. Since I am unable to replicate his error I was hoping someone else had run into a similar issue.

Comment: What happens when you create a UK account yourself and authenticate with that?

Comment: I have created a UK account and used it to authenticate without issue. Worked just as it should have.

Comment: Next step is remote desktop with them. Make sure they are pressing the right buttons in the right order

Comment: I once had some strange behaviour I couldn't replicate on my website. I told my father to place an order. I watched him create the exact issue everyone else complained about... by pushing "enter" after typing the quantity.